# Django searching for a string match in a list of dictionary which is returned from queryset.

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have something like this in my view.py

```
def calculateMark(mobile_a, mobile_b):
    #variables
    mobile_a = mobile_a
    mobile_b = mobile_b

    results_a = []
    results_b = []
    record_a = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name=mobile_a).values()
    record_b = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name=mobile_b).values()
    results_a += record_a
    results_b += record_b
    record_a = record_a[0]
    record_b = record_b[0]

    if 'Android' in record_a['os']:
        os_mark_a = 8.9
    elif 'Android' in record_b['os']:
        os_mark_b = 8.9
    elif 'iOS' in record_a['os']:
        os_mark_a = 14
    if 'iOS' in record_b['os']:
        os_mark_b = 14
    else:
        os_mark_a = 1
        os_mark_b = 1
```

calculateMark Function will calculate a mark for mobiles. Everything is ok but in case of Operating System (os) testing. Its returning always the else block.

The question is how can I search for a string like "ios" in my record['os'] field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe your problem is the `if` in the following line:

```
if 'iOS' in record_b['os']:
```

As a result of this code in every case other than iOS in `record_b`, both `os_mark_a` and `os_mark_b` will be set to `1`. Even if they were set to another value before, they will be overwritten by `1`. To correct this particular problem change the line to:

```
elif 'iOS' in record_b['os']:
```

There are other things I find weird:

- In most cases you set just one of `os_mark_b` or `os_mark_a`, leaving
  the other one unset. You could correct this for example by settings
  both to a default value first.
- You don't need to load the values to a dictionary using `values()` - just use `.get()` and use the resulting object directly. Among other benefits this would eliminate lines 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13 completely.
- Calculations for A and B seem completely separate. It seems it would be wiser to create a smaller method that calucaltes mark for a single object.
- Your method doesn't return anything. I presume that's only because it's a simplified example.
- What's the following code is about? That doesn't do anything...

  ```
  mobile_a = mobile_a
  mobile_b = mobile_b
  ```

**Update:** Example of code without those issues:

```
def calculateMark(mobile):
    record = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.get(mobile_name=mobile)

    if 'Android' in record.os:
        return 8.9
    if 'iOS' in record.os:
        return 14
    return 1
```

**Update 2:** Also, since we already got so far in making this code better - this shouldn't be a separate function, but a method on a `TechSpecificationAdd` object.

```
class TechSpecificationAdd(models.Model):
    # some fields

    def calculateMark(self):
        if 'Android' in self.os:
            return 8.9
        if 'iOS' in self.os:
            return 14
        return 1
```

You would then use this in your code like this:

```
record = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.get(mobile_name=mobile)
mark = record.calculateMark()
```

Comment: oops! thanks for your correction Ludwik Buddy. But another correction I have to make in the third "if". It should be "elif".

Comment: I updated my post after you accepted it, adding some additional thoughts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. The function doesn't return anything..... it's just simplifying. Thanks for the idea of making another function for calculating mark. And the .get() issue, does it like this following?
try:
    e = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.get(id='weight')
    b = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.get(id='os')
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print("Either the entry doesn't exist.")

Comment: Hey, Ludwik I have other fields to calculate except 'os' like 'weight', 'resolution' etc. Now I am making each variable for each issue like "weight_mark_a", "weight_mark_b" and finally I am adding those in a "tech_mark_a" variable. I am not doing increment operator in an each calculation like "tech_mark_a = +1", if an item get marks. Because I have to show the individual mark for individual item in template. Is it ok or I am missing some simple solution?

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44021/discussion-between-ali-hayder-and-ludwik-trammer)